# iAd is Not Showing on device after releasing App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iad

I had an app approved about 8hours ago, during development my iAds were working fine and I was receiving test ads in the simulator and on my iPhone. But I've downloaded the official version and so have a few of my friends and we're not receiving any ads no matter how long the app stays open. In the iAds Network area of iTunes connect it says that my app is receiving live ads.

Can someone please telL me if i've done something wrong and what can i do to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently iAd is supported in some of the countries. Because of this it might be possible you are not able to see the ads.

Supported Countries,

```
iAd campaigns currently run in the U.S, Canada, Mexico, U.K., France, Germany, Italy, Spain, Australia, New Zealand, and Japan.
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you enabled the display of advertisements in your app's iTunes Connect page while it was in edit mode. A friend of mine, who is also a developer, said that it can take two weeks before you start seeing the first ads in the official version of your approved app.